# How to build this XML namespace?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I was trying to create some guest user XML files (using Pythong etree) for the Cisco ISE Guest API and was stuck in how to create the namespaces portion (see below bold).

```
**<ns4:guestuser description="ERS Example user " id="123456789" name="guestuser"  xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns4="identity.ers.ise.cisco.com">**

element...
element...
</ns4:guestuser>
```

Below is part of my Python program...Did I do it wrongly? How can I insert that long string of namespace starting from description="ERS Example user "..?

Any suggestion/help will be much appreciated..

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def buildTree(name):
root = ET.Element("ns4:guestuser")
<snip>
<snip>

 tree.write("user1.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`attrib` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) to add element attributes :

```
>>> attributes = {"description":"ERS Example user ", "id":"123456789", "name":"guestuser", " xmlns:ers":"ers.ise.cisco.com", "xmlns:xs":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:ns4":"identity.ers.ise.cisco.com"}
>>> root = ET.Element("ns4:guestuser", attrib=attributes)
>>> print ET.tostring(root)
<ns4:guestuser  xmlns:ers="ers.ise.cisco.com" description="ERS Example user " id="123456789" name="guestuser" xmlns:ns4="identity.ers.ise.cisco.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```